# Is it possible to use the generic "in" and "out" modifier on the same T?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

This code is invalid because T can't have the in and out modifier at the same time:

```
public interface IInOut<in out T>
{

}
```

But you can do this "workaround":

```
public interface IInOutWorkaround<in TIn, out TOut>
{
    TOut Test(TIn value);
}

public class InOutWorkaround<T> : IInOutWorkaround<T, T>
{
    public T Test(T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The second example works and the InOutWorkaround class has the same type for TIn and TOut, so why is it not possible to add both modifier to the same T directly in the interface? Or is it possible with a different syntax?

Comment: Generics are about allowing as many types to be used as possible, **without** breaking compile time type safety. How would that work with co and Contravariance on a single type, at the same time?

Comment: Adding `in` and `out` to an interface is not about input and output, but about covariance and contravariance: http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/01/c-understanding-in-and-out-generic-modifier/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could have interfaces `IReadable<out T> { T read(int index); }`, `IWritable<in T> { void write(int index, T dat);`, `ISplitReadWrite<out Tout, in Tin>:IReadable<Tout>,IWritable<Tin>`, and `IReadWrite<T>:ISplitReadWrite<T,T>`.

If one has a class `MyCollection<T>` which implements `IReadWrite<T>`, then a `MyCollection<Cat>` could be converted to `IReadable<Animal>`, `IWritable<SiameseCat>`, or an `ISplitReadWrite<Animal,SiameseCat>`.  Note, however, that the only `IReadable<T>` that would yield an item that could be stored into a `MyCollection<Cat>` would be `IReadable<Cat>`, the only `IWritable<T>` that could handle everything that might appear in a `MyCollection<Cat>` would be `IWritable<Cat>`.  The only forms of `ISplitReadWrite<Tout,Tin>` that would allow one to read out an item and write it back *to the same collection* without a cast would be those where the two types were the same, and the only such type implemented by `MyCollection<Cat>` would be `ISplitReadWrite<Cat,Cat>`.

Note that one could have an interface with methods that could be equally usable with `MyCollection<Animal>` and `MyCollection<SiameseCat>`, such as "swap the items in slots i1 and i2 of the same collection", but such an interface *wouldn't need any generic parameter at all*.  Id one has an `IPermutable` interface, it could include methods like `void swapItems(int i1, int i2);` which wouldn't have any generic types in their signatures, and thus wouldn't make it necessary for the type to include any generic type arguments.

Comment: The other answers are good too, but I accepted this answer, because it shows a example to get the in and out behaviour properly by splitting the interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

`in T` says that T can *not* be used covariantly, and `out T` says that T can *not* be used contravariantly.  Your `in out T` would therefore mean that the type can *not* be used covariantly and can *not* be used contravariantly, which means it'd be *invariant*.  So in effect that would behave identically to just writing `public interface IInOut<T>`, because when no `in` or `out` modifiers are used the generic type is considered *invariant*.

In the case of your class `InOutWorkaround<T>`, `T` is still invariant, so the fact that you're using it as both an `in` and `out` type is fine, because it's invariant, as it meets both restrictions.  If you were attempting to have a type that could be used *both* covariantly and contravariantly, your workaround didn't achieve that, because the `T` in `InOutWorkaround` is *invariant* (because all generic type arguments for all classes are invariant).  That generic type argument cannot be used either covariantly or contravariantly.

Comment: `in T` [says that the type is contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier), and `out T` [says that the type is covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier).  

The fact that an `in T` type can _not_ be used covariantly, and an `out T` type can _not_ be used contravariantly, are consequences of the [definition of covariance and contravariance](https://w.wiki/HJT). They are not implied by the generic modifiers themselves, as you answer seems to suggest.

Comment: @alelom I wasn't quoting the spec or other documentation.  I was describing the meaning of those keywords *in my own words*, because I felt that it would be more understandable for people in this situation.  Had I intended to quote anything, I'd have indicated as such in the answer.

Comment: sure, I was just trying to highlight that the sentence "`in T` says that T can not be used covariantly" is not technically correct, and the same for the other sentence. I still upvoted you as I liked your answer, and I find your sentences useful.

Comment: @alelom But it is technically correct.  You've quoted someone using *different words to describe the exact same thing*.  Had I stated I was quoting the specs, you could indeed point out that the specs use different phrasing.  I used my own words, and phrased *the same thing* a different way, one that happens to make it more apparent what's going on in this particular situation.  I of course wouldn't describe this behavior this way in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Extending Variant Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces#extending-variant-generic-interfaces) specification

> The compiler does not infer the variance from the interface that is
> being extended. You can create an interface that extends both the interface where the
> generic type parameter `T` is covariant and the interface where it is
> contravariant if in the extending interface the generic type parameter
> `T` is invariant.

```cs
interface ICovariant<out T> { }
interface IContravariant<in T> { }
interface IInvariant<T> : ICovariant<T>, IContravariant<T> { }
```

This example looks like as an exactly your case, `T` is invariant generic type parameter in `InOutWorkaround<T>` interface, compiler doesn't infer (or inherit it in extending interface), so your workaround is pointless

```cs
public class InOutWorkaround<T> : IInOutWorkaround<T, T>
{
    public T Test(T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```